# How to pass pointer to int when have got int?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have got a code:

```
void fun1(int ** i) {
 *i = new int(0);
}
void fun2(int *& i) {
    i = new int(69);
}
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int a = new int(42);
    fun1(&a);
    cout << "fun1" << a << endl;

    fun2(&a);
    cout << "fun2" << a << endl;
}
```

And I want to pass "a" into functions fun1 and fun2. Can I do it without creating a pointer that will point to a? Can I pass "a" somehow?

Comment: No, as far as I'm aware, you'll have to create a separate pointer to a in these cases.

Comment: Did you mean: `int* a = new int(42);`?

Comment: You seems to have a couple typos but [this works for me](http://ideone.com/Kjq5Vd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the functions takes a pointer to a pointer:

```
void fun1(int ** i)
```

the other one takes a reference to a pointer:

```
void fun1(int *& i)
```

Calling them without having a pointer variable is rather pointless, as those functions main effect (most likely) is to change the adress the passed pointer (passed by reference, either as pointer or reference) is pointing to so that it can be used by the caller.

Lets suppose the following would work

```
int a;
fun1(&(&a));
```

The function would change the adress the "temporary" (`&a` which is a pointer to int) is pointing to, but you would have no means to access it.

Comment: You can't pass `&a` to `fun1` because `&a` is not a pointer to a pointer, it is a pointer to an int. That line won't compile. The closest you can get is to declare a pointer to a and then call the function: `int*p = &a; fun1( &p );` and it is still as you said, pointless, because the `int a;` variable is no longer being pointed to.

Comment: @DavidRector ups you are right, I will edit it

Comment: You can't write &(&a) because &a is rvalue.

Comment: @Lassie sure I can write it, it just wont compile, thats why I wrote "suppose the following would work"

Answer (score 1):

1st of all `int a = new int(42);` is wrong the operator `new` creates the object on the heap and returns the pointer to the newly created object. you are trying to assign it to an `int`. at best it should look like `int* a = new int; *a = 42;` at which time your code is responsible for deleting it.
Now if you have a function like void `func(int* pA) {}` and have a local variable like `int a = 42;` and you want to pass it to your function, you would call your function like `func(&a);`.
2nd both your functions are creating memory leak. you are creating a new pointer that is never deleted.
3rd if you want to change the value of a in your functions, all you need is something like this:

```
void func1(int* pA)
{
   *pA = 42;
}
```

or you can do something like this:

```
void func2(int& rA)
    {
       rA = 42;
    }
```

I think you have not understood the meaning of pointer and references.

Comment: for func1 how would you pass an int* into the function to get the pointer equal to 42?

Answer (score 0):

To have a reference without pointer, just do `foo(int &a) {a = 43}` and call the function like this: `foo(a)`

Answer (score 0):

Operator new returns pointer, so you must write `int* a = new int(42);`. After you can call the functions as follows:

```
fun1(&a);
fun2(a);
```

And also don't forget to delete allocated memory with new:

```
#include <iostream>
void fun1(int ** i)
{
    delete *i;
    *i = new int(0);
}
void fun2(int *& i)
{
    delete i;
    i = new int(69);
}
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int *a = new int(42);
    fun1(&a);
    cout << "fun1: " << a << endl;
    fun2(a);
    cout << "fun2: " << a << endl;
    delete a;
}
```